# Codeigniter Could not find the language line

Tags: php, codeigniter, localization

I just start to test my new app on a web server (OVH). It is localized (uk + fr).
Everything works fine in my `localhost` (wamp) but when online I don’t have any text.

Here the config :

```
$config['language'] = 'english'; 
Reps : application/language/english/
```

Here is the log :

```
DEBUG - 2014-10-26 14:39:20 --> Helper loaded: language_helper
File loaded: app5f47k3dd/views/admin/head.php
ERROR - 2014-10-26 14:39:20 --> Could not find the language line "info_need_register"
ERROR - 2014-10-26 14:39:20 --> Could not find the language line "btn_register"
ERROR - 2014-10-26 14:39:20 --> Could not find the language line "info_sign_in"
ERROR - 2014-10-26 14:39:20 --> Could not find the language line "fld_email"
etc.
```

I tried a lot of things without any success. If you already saw this issue... or any line of search would be welcome.

EDIT : I just found why. I had a bad filename  Languageloader.php instead of languageloader.php...

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
'class' => 'LanguageLoader',
'function' => 'initialize',
'filename' => 'languageloader.php',
'filepath' => 'hooks');
```

Comment: **Everything works fine in my localhost (wamp) but when inline I don’t have any text.** so he probably means **O**nline

Comment: Could you please share your configuration and language directory structure for solve localization problem? Means share config files line 72 (`$config['language'] = 'english';`) and application>language directory structure.

Comment: Yes "Online" sorry.
$config['language'] = 'english';
And my reps : application/language/english/
And the files

Comment: Btw thx Arif, your question makes me go to the good way ;)